# angular dragdrop drag across ng repeat elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-dragdrop

here is the plunkr which will best illustrate my problem.

https://plnkr.co/edit/VrT7TmK6tY2u4k2NYJ2U?p=preview

there are two panels the panel on the left has a list of items that you can drag and drop onto wells on the right.  the wells are created with a ng repeat. unfortunately I can not drag from one well to the another well on the right side of the screen. not sure why.

```
 <div ng-controller="oneCtrl"><!--one-->



              <div class="span3" style='margin-left:10px;'>

                <div class="thumbnail"
                data-drop="true" 
                ng-model='list1'
                data-jqyoui-options="optionsList1"
                jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">



                    <div class="alert alert-info btn-draggable"
                      ng-repeat="item in list1"
                      ng-show="item.title" data-drag="{{item.drag}}"
                      data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}"
                      ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}"
                      ><!--alert-->

                        {{item.title}}

                    </div><!--alert-->


                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="span3" style='margin-left:150px;'>

                <div class=thumbnail>

                   <div class="well"
                   ng-repeat = "org in orgs"
                    data-drop="true"
                    ng-model="org.list"
                    data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'.btn-draggable:not([ng-model=org.list])'}" 
                    jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">

                    <div class=" alert alert-success btn-draggable" ng-repeat="item in org.list" 
                    ng-show="item.title" 
                    data-drag="{{item.drag}}"
                    data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}"
                    ng-model="org.list"
                    jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}">
                      {{item.title}}
                    </div>

                </div>


                </div>


              </div>





      </div><!--one-->
```

and the javascript

var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop']);

```
App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.orgs = [
      {name: 'org1', list: []},
      {name: 'org2', list: []},
      {name: 'org3', list: []},

    ]


  $scope.list1 = [
    { 'title': 'Item 1', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 2', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 3', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 4', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 5', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 6', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 7', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 8', 'drag': true }
  ];


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have `data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'.btn-draggable:not([ng-model=org.list])'}"` for the repeater in the right panel. This selector is the same for all the generated droppable-zones and [it controls which draggable elements are accepted by the droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept). You will be able to drag and drop the items between the generated zones, if you will remove this option (or modify it according to your requirements).

[Working plnkr.](https://plnkr.co/edit/d6hgwWwZrJAbfzsAR4g5?p=preview)